# How to implement server headers configuration for images cache busting?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cache-control

I have floowing headers on my images:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:public, must-revalidate
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:10003
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Thu, 20 Jul 2017 17:36:23 GMT
ETag:"2713-55493e9ae6740"
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Last-Modified:Tue, 18 Jul 2017 09:12:21 GMT
Server:Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
```

But IE11 (might any modern browsers as well) doesn't reload the image. I assume if I set "must-revalidate" option for cache-control header browser will compare modification date and will download new image if dates are different.

There is no any other option except different filenames then?

Comment: Does the ETag change between 2 reloads? If not, you've got your culprit. I would disable ETag and see what happens

Comment: Yep after i change file ETAG is changed, 
from 31a-554cf0c026400 to 31a-554cf0e36f740 but ie11 only loads new image if i press f5, if i click on a logo (which reloads the same page again) old image shown.